# NSDictionary Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, plist

I have a dictionary like this:

```
["day": 
[["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "08:00", "fine": "08:10"],
 ["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "08:02", "fine": "08:03"], 
 ["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "08:04", "fine": "08:05"],
 ["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "08:06", "fine": "08:07"], 
 ["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "08:08", "fine": "08:09"],
 ["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "09:00", "fine": "10:00"]],  


"martedì": 
[["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "08:00", "fine": "08:10"],
 ["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "08:02", "fine": "08:03"],
 ["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "08:04", "fine": "08:05"],
 ["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "08:00", "fine": "08:10"],
 ["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "08:02", "fine": "08:03"],
 ["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "08:04", "fine": "08:05"]
```

How can I get an array with only subject of "day"? How can I get an array with only "inizio" + "fine" ?

Comment: can you format your dict in multi-line to make it easier to read and maybe provide an example of the desired result, e.g.: `let day = [ whatever is the result ]`

Comment: Maybe you could come up with a better title, one that describes your question and specially something without NSDictionary since that is completely irrelevant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get variables from NSDictionary in a Plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57392031/get-variables-from-nsdictionary-in-a-plist)

Comment: You have a Dictionary that contains 2 keys, "day" and "martedi". Each of those keys contains arrays of dictionaries. You want to take the contents of the "day" key and map it to an array of just the  "inizio" + "fine" key/value pairs?

Comment: You said in a comment to one of the answers: "I want an array with all the materia value: for example print(arrayDay) Log: Matematica, Matematica, Matematica". But yet in your question you say "How can I get an array with only "inizio" + "fine" ?" Can you edit your question to state your goal more clearly?

Comment: Yes, I need an array with the value of "materia" key and and an array with the value of strings "inizio" + "fine".
I try to have the value of "materia" key but that's the error:
 print(values["materia"]!)  - Type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'

Comment: I write on the dictionary in another class with the function: 

`func readScheduleFile() -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
    var swiftDictionary = Dictionary<String, Any>()
    for day in self.scheduleDictionary {
        let key = day.key as! String
        let nsArray = day.value as! NSArray
        var swiftArray = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()
        for hour in nsArray {
            let dictionary = hour as! Dictionary<String, String>
            swiftArray.append(dictionary)
        }
        swiftDictionary[key] = swiftArray
    }
    return swiftDictionary
}`

Comment: Don't post duplicate questions. Edit your original question to include all the details.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you want to take the contents of the "day" key and map it to an array of just the "inizio" + "fine" key/value pairs:

```
let dict = [
    "day":
        [
            ["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "08:00", "fine": "08:10"],
            ["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "08:02", "fine": "08:03"],
            ["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "08:04", "fine": "08:05"],
            ["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "08:06", "fine": "08:07"],
            ["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "08:08", "fine": "08:09"],
            ["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "09:00", "fine": "10:00"]
    ],
    "martedì":
        [
            ["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "08:00", "fine": "08:10"],
            ["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "08:02", "fine": "08:03"],
            ["materia": "Matematica", "inizio": "08:04", "fine": "08:05"]
    ]
]

//Extract the value of the "day" keyfrom the dictionary. If we can't, crash.
guard let dayArray = dict["day"] else {
    fatalError("splat")
}
//Filter the array to only those entries that contain both 
//  an "inizio" key/value pair
//  a "fine" key/value pair
let inizio_fine = dayArray.filter { $0["inizio"] != nil && $0["fine"] != nil }

//Now map that filtered array to an array of 
//just the "inizio" + "fine" key/value pairs
    .map {
        ["inizio": $0["inizio"]!,
         "fine": $0["fine"]!]
}

print(inizio_fine)
```